# How to performe a null-check for an empty Optional

Tags: java, java-8, repository

I'm currently working with some repository functions, like `.findById()`. Now I want to check, if there was an entry returned for the requested id. I'm currently doing this by performing a `null`-check.

```
Optional<Entry> entryOptional = entryRepository.findById(id);

if (entryOptional != null) {
  // do sth. ...
}
```

The `.findById()` documentation says, that the function will...

> return the entity with the given id or `Optional#empty()` if
>   none found

So is my current implementation with the `null-check` working as expected? Or do I have to check something like:

```
if (!entryOptional.isEmpty()) {
  // do sth. ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking whether an optional is null or not is intrinsically wrong.

Optionals where created in order to negate the need for null checks, by introducing the notion of emptiness.

Essentially an optional is a wrapper for a value, for which it can have two states. Either having a value or being empty. This is done via using `Optional#isPresent`. You can check more on this on the related documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--).

What this does essentially is the following:

```
public boolean isPresent() {
    return value != null;
}
```

A nicely implemented method (as the one you mention above) will either return an optional with a value or an empty Optional (as it is mentioned in the documentation).

Optionals offer a good amount of methods that you can operate of them without the need for emptiness checks.

For example, in your code you could:

```
entryRepository.findById(id).ifPresent(() -> {
   //some operation
});
```

Which basically accepts an consumer and executes it in case the value of the optional is not null.

Alternative you could use mapping functions etc etc.

I suggest you have a good look at the documentation for more.

Answer (score 2):

> So is my current implementation with the null-check working as expected?

No. Like the method says, it returns the entity, or `Optional.empty`; it does not return `null`.

Your second version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`Optional`s are created to remove `null` checks on that field and to do operations on that field without the care of it being null.

You can check with `Optional.isPresent()` at the end if it contains any value or not.

So yes, your second approach is correct.